# Reverse an insertion sort C#

Tags: c#

I have a working implementation of the insertion sort in c#, however i need the values to be stored in decreasing order. My current implementation gives me the numbers in a increasing order. But im unsure on how to reverse it. A is my array.

```
for (i = 1; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    int value = A[i];
    j = i - 1;
    while ((j >= 0) && (A[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
    {
        A[j + 1] = A[j];
        j--;
    }
    A[j + 1] = value;
}

Console.WriteLine("\nSorted\n");
foreach (int x in A)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Unless this is an academic pursuit, wouldn't it be better to use existing sorting/reversing implementations in .Net?

Comment: @spender Unfortunately this is for an academic purpose, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
while ((j >= 0) && (A[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
```

with this:

```
while ((j >= 0) && (A[j].CompareTo(value) < 0))
```

Comment: Great, i don't know why i didn't see that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to sort your array:

```
A.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Or sorting it descending (reversed):

```
A.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Comment: Good point but i was hoping i could rework the logic of the algorithm, any more sorting takes a long time when working with a very large amount of numbers

Comment: @MichaelHancock How large is your array then?

Answer (score 1):

You want to reverse the array? Use `Array.Reverse`:

```
Array.Reverse(A);
```

If you instead want to order it by the numbers, you can use LINQ:

```
A = A.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
A = A.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToArray();
```

If the array is already ordered `Array.Reverse` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the algorithm, simply reverse the comparison

```
while ((j >= 0) && (A[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
```

to this

```
while ((j >= 0) && (A[j].CompareTo(value) < 0)) // note that it reads '< 0'
```

to reverse the condition on which you're checking.